# Is the Websocket protocol supported on Android?

Tags: browser

I haven't been able to find much information on the state of Websocket implementation. Is it currently supported in the stock Android browser? If not, are there any browsers for Android that do support it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the stock Android browser (Chrome) doesn't have support for Websocket. But other browsers e.g. Opera has support for it in the latest release, but it's disabled.

See [Compatibility tables for support of HTML5](http://caniuse.com/#agents=mobile&feat=namevalue-storage,offline-apps,websockets,webworkers)

Answer (score 3):

Neither Gingerbread nor Honeycomb browsers support web sockets. However, Firefox Beta v.7 and Firefox Aurora (which is a nightly of v. 8) both support the current spec of web sockets off the box.

Answer (score -1):

The browser in Honeycomb 3.2 does support WebSockets.

Comment: Could you backup this answer with an link (maybe to an changelog entry or announcement)?

Answer (score -1):

Just did a little investigation...

My Xoom (currently up to date), does NOT support the following:

WebSockets,
  SSE (Server Sent Events),
  WebWorkers,
  getUserMedia();

:( x4

Comment: I think the answer would be more awesome if you also tell how you did the investigation.